# About Data Dictionary

Tags: x++, axapta, dynamics-ax-2012, data-dictionary

I'm working with Dynamics ax 2012.

I'm finding a way to create foreign key with dynamics ax.

I try to create new -> relation -> new -> foreignkey -> primarykey based

I successfully created this relation but when I look the database in SQLSERVER2008 i think ((the relation)) the foreign key is not created !

And what about the primary key !! what can i do to create my personal key other then "RecId" !!

If one day i want to import a database created with SQLSERVER2008 to Dynamics AX will it be possible ? and how do I do that ?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry but table relations are for the benefit of the AX environment, it is not synced to the database. Basically only fields and indexes are synced.

Can you make an AX database from an SQL database?

It probably could be done using a good deal of X++ programming doing ODBC reads from the source database meta tables. I don't know if anyone have tried it, but I doubt it.

You are most likely better off by a total database redesign, as the [AX data dictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa588039) contains more information than the SQL database.

How would you convert an SQL Database to use [Valid Time State Tables and Date Effective Data](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg861781)?

Comment: about your question : Can you make an AX database from an SQL database? 
i think not ! i try to do it but i can't ! when i make table in SQLSERVER i can not see it in dynamics ax 2012 ! i don't know why

Comment: Because, it is not the way things work! Create the table in AX, then it will instantly appear in the SQL Server. Not the other way around.